# How to make my ListView items clickable?

Tags: android, listview

I am extremely new in android. I am making a listview and every time i click on a list's item, it should open a new activity. In this case Settings activity. I have tried many ways but none have worked. Any kind of help would be appreciated. This is my code:

```
package com.alex.mylist;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Settings extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        ListView lstSettings = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstSettings);
        lstSettings.getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Register.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [listView.setOnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html)  to make listview items clickable

```
lstSettings.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Settings.this,
                                             Register.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @MavrosGatos : most welcome friend. if it's working then just mark it as answer by click on Right sign on upper corner of answer.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set an ItemSelectedListener or ItemClickListener for your listview.

```
listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ListView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // call Activity
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

});

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // call activity
    }

});
```